# Why does moving/deleting files "stall" on my PC?

Tags: performance, file-transfer, speed

My PC is Windows 10, 8GB RAM and a 2.8GHz processor.

Basically, to give you an idea, whenever I drag any item onto the desktop or into a folder the file takes a long time to appear and I have to click on another folder or minimise it and then go back in to make it appear. Same goes for deleting too. This happens with all files from small images to larger zipped files.

Comment: How many files are you deleting/moving? How fast is your harddrive? What background processes are running?

Comment: @Burgi this can happen if I move one small jpeg. Sorry, I'm not sure how fast my HDD is.

Comment: Has it always done this or only since moving to Win10? What about background processes like AV? Can you try the [performance logger](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/5-ways-to-open-performance-monitor-on-windows-10.html) while moving files? Is the disk internal or USB?

Comment: Have you run a chkdsk lately?

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason: Hard drive is failing.  Could be that the drive has one or more bad sectors that the file has been previously written to, this will cause it to stall or falter.  This can even lock up the computer.

Time to backup/replace the drive.

Sucks, but I've been through it too.. going through it now, actually, as I am preparing to replace a drive, so I'm removing the files to an external backup and getting the drive out for disposal..

Good luck!

Comment: As an added note, if the OP would like to perform diagnostics to confirm the drive is failing (which I agree, it likely is) they should first backup any important data. Running diagnostics can push a failing drive over the edge and make it fail completely.